# ActiveMQ Advisory Topics for Connections not forwarded in network of brokers?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, nms

I'm working on an application where we want to monitor logon/logoff of clients. Since ActiveMQ contains Advisory Topics that alert you of new connections and removal of connections, the idea was to use this advisory messages ( ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection). This worked fine during development but now, when we are going to production in our network of brokers, we noticed that the messages from remote brokers in the network are not getting to our consumer.

Our setup is:

Producer
     |
Broker A and B ( master Slave) in site 1 -> These have a duplex network connector to our public brokers (C & D)

Broker C and D (master slave again) in site 2

and attached to C and D, we have the "consumers" of whom we want to know logon/logoff information.

When we take a look at the advisory topic in the admin console on Broker A, we see the subscriber and we get logon messages if we let a consumer connect. On Broker C, I don't see any subscribers on the advisory topic, and when a consumers logs on / OFF, we don't see the advisory message.

Is this behaviour by default or am i missing a config?

Comment: Is the advisory disabled in the XML config on Broker C?
<broker advisorySupport="false">

Comment: Nope.I also do get other advisories. And i get the logon/logoff advisories on the local machine but i don't see them being forwarded through the network of brokers

Answer (score 1):

There are different places you need to look for:

- Check that your broker configuration does not disable them: in your broker configuration (A,B,C,D), check that the advisory are not disable (we shouldn't get any `<broker advisorySupport="false">`. Normally this seems to be checked already
- Check that your code does not disable it `broker.setAdvisorySupport(false);`. This should not seem to be the root cause since it works in development environment
- Are your destinations dynamic? Check the following page of [Network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html), especially the section "Dynamic networks"